# Django rest-auth PUT method returning JSON Unexpected token

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, put

I've been trying to try to do this for a couple of days for now. I am trying to update the user's data through put method in Django using rest framework. However, I've been receiving this error message in the console.
[image]

This is the fetch function that is used to send the data to the backend. As it's shown, I'm even trying to compare it to other fetch methods and I think nothing is wrong with the body of the fetch.

Below are my codes used to update the data.

[image]

views.py

[image]

serializers.py

[image]

urls.py
[image]

Answer (score 1):

So, the error is

> Unexpected token < in JSON

which means that it tried to parse a response containing a character `<`. If I had to guess, the response is a HTML document, because it would start with `<` (`<html>...`).

For instance, it can be a 404 error page because the URL was not found. The best way to know is, instead of logging `response.json()`, just log `response.text()`. Until you do that, hard to know what really happens.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ALwed0l 
This is what I get, and I think the error is from the backend which I have little-to-no experience with.

Comment: The body is `ReadableStream`. My mistake, try to log `response.text()`. I edit the answer.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/AtWz7Nb It just responses some useless htmls i guess

Comment: @KyiZin it is not useless at all. If you read the content, it is a HTML document that contains an `AssertionError`, and it tells you where. That should allow you to continue. It looks like an error response handled by Django (REST framework).

Comment: Also you don't need your frontend app to debug this. You can test your endpoints with 1) a Python testing framework 2) Postman 3) typing the URL in your browser (if you haven't set up authorization yet). The latter will display the HTML error you got beautifully.

Comment: Thank you for your kind replies and help. The URL is working fine to a point. Since I don't have Postman installed, all it replies is "Authentication credentials are not provided" like here https://imgur.com/a/tuunScE

Comment: At this point there is way too much for this question. You should post another more focused question (this is why it got downvoted probably). Try disabling auth temporarily to see if it is the cause, or just to ease debugging.

Comment: Getting downvotes are okay. Nothing is sadder than the project due at September 1st and you have promised your teacher 3 things to be finished and you haven’t even finished one and other subjects are also giving more assignments. Haha just some sense of humor. I do really appreciate your help. Thank you!